# Any ideas about the solution to this nonlinear ODE? $-u''-\frac{1}{r}u'+e^u-e^{-u} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is $-u''-\frac{1}{r}u'+e^u-e^{-u} = 0$, where u is a function of $r$ (i.e. $u(r)$) and $u\in C^2\{(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\}$. No initial condition is provided, so just try to find the general solution.
This question appears when I tried to find the fundamental solution of $-\Delta u + e^u - e^{-u} = \delta (\vec{x})$ in 2-D, where $\Delta$ stands for the Laplace operator and $\delta(\vec{x})$ stands for the Dirac's function. Since the pde equation is  radially symmetric, it's reasonable to think $u$ as a univariate function of $r$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $r=e^t$ ,

Then $t=\ln r$

$\dfrac{du}{dr}=\dfrac{du}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dr}=\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{du}{dt}=e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}=\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)=\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)\dfrac{dt}{dr}=\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}-e^{-t}\dfrac{du}{dt}\right)e^{-t}=e^{-2t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}-e^{-2t}\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore-e^{-2t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}+e^{-2t}\dfrac{du}{dt}-e^{-2t}\dfrac{du}{dt}+e^u-e^{-u}=0$

$e^{-2t}\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}=e^u-e^{-u}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dt^2}=e^{2t+u}-e^{2t-u}$

Comment: Yes, this transformation is right and beautiful, but I don't know how to carry on. Would you explain the following steps please?

Comment: @U2647 You can rewrite the equation as $u'' = 2\exp(2t)\sinh(u)$, but there will be no closed form solution. If you seek solutions for $u$ near $0$, you can say $\sinh(u)\approx u$ and find solutions in terms of the modified Bessel functions.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 So the approximate solution includes an imaginary part?

Comment: @U2647 They are real-valued functions for real and positive arguments.